# how to separate codegen for special operator?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have many *explode* function in one compute. It oom.[heap dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouNTv.png)

I found *explode* function will codegen in one class, the intermediate result will be buffered in memory.
[spark web ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iw8uh.png)
How can i avoid this promble? separate codegen?

```
 public Object generate(Object[] references) {
        return new GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1(references);
    }

    /*wsc_codegenStageId*/
    final class GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1 extends org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator {
        private Object[] references;
        private scala.collection.Iterator[] inputs;
        private scala.collection.Iterator scan_input_0;
        private boolean generate_generate_isNull_3_0;
        private boolean generate_generate_isNull_14_0;
        private org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter[] scan_mutableStateArray_0 = new org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter[10];

        public GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1(Object[] references) {
            this.references = references;
        }

        public void init(int index, scala.collection.Iterator[] inputs) {
            partitionIndex = index;
            this.inputs = inputs;
            scan_input_0 = inputs[0];
            scan_mutableStateArray_0[0] = new org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter(1, 32);
            scan_mutableStateArray_0[1] = new org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter(1, 32);

            scan_mutableStateArray_0[2] = new org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter(2, 64);
            scan_mutableStateArray_0[3] = new org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter(2, 64);
            scan_mutableStateArray_0[4] = new org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter(2, 64);
            scan_mutableStateArray_0[5] = new org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter(3, 96);
            scan_mutableStateArray_0[6] = new org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter(3, 96);
            scan_mutableStateArray_0[7] = new org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter(3, 96);
            scan_mutableStateArray_0[8] = new org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter(4, 128);
            scan_mutableStateArray_0[9] = new org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter(4, 128);

        }

        private void generate_doConsume_2(UTF8String generate_expr_0_2, boolean generate_exprIsNull_0_2, UTF8String generate_expr_1_1, UTF8String generate_expr_2_0) throws java.io.IOException {
            ArrayData generate_value_26 = null;
            generate_value_26 = new org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.GenericArrayData(generate_expr_1_1.split(((UTF8String) references[7] /* literal */), -1));

            int generate_numElements_2 = false ? 0 : generate_value_26.numElements();
            for (int generate_index_2 = 0; generate_index_2 < generate_numElements_2; generate_index_2++) {
                ((org.apache.spark.sql.execution.metric.SQLMetric) references[8] /* numOutputRows */).add(1);

// common sub-expressions

                UTF8String generate_col_2 = generate_value_26.getUTF8String(generate_index_2);
                scan_mutableStateArray_0[9].reset();

                scan_mutableStateArray_0[9].zeroOutNullBytes();

                if (generate_exprIsNull_0_2) {
                    scan_mutableStateArray_0[9].setNullAt(0);
                } else {
                    scan_mutableStateArray_0[9].write(0, generate_expr_0_2);
                }

                scan_mutableStateArray_0[9].write(1, generate_expr_1_1);

                scan_mutableStateArray_0[9].write(2, generate_expr_2_0);

                scan_mutableStateArray_0[9].write(3, generate_col_2);
                append((scan_mutableStateArray_0[9].getRow()).copy());

            }

        }

        private void generate_doConsume_1(UTF8String generate_expr_0_1, boolean generate_exprIsNull_0_1, UTF8String generate_expr_1_0) throws java.io.IOException {
            generate_generate_isNull_14_0 = true;
            UTF8String generate_value_14 = null;
            do {
                if (!generate_exprIsNull_0_1) {
                    generate_generate_isNull_14_0 = false;
                    generate_value_14 = generate_expr_0_1;
                    continue;
                }

                if (!false) {
                    generate_generate_isNull_14_0 = false;
                    generate_value_14 = ((UTF8String) references[4] /* literal */);
                    continue;
                }

            } while (false);

            ArrayData generate_value_13 = null;
            generate_value_13 = new org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.GenericArrayData(generate_value_14.split(((UTF8String) references[5] /* literal */), -1));

            int generate_numElements_1 = false ? 0 : generate_value_13.numElements();
            for (int generate_index_1 = 0; generate_index_1 < generate_numElements_1; generate_index_1++) {
                ((org.apache.spark.sql.execution.metric.SQLMetric) references[6] /* numOutputRows */).add(1);

// common sub-expressions

                UTF8String generate_col_1 = generate_value_13.getUTF8String(generate_index_1);

                generate_doConsume_2(generate_expr_0_1, generate_exprIsNull_0_1, generate_expr_1_0, generate_col_1);

            }

        }

        protected void processNext() throws java.io.IOException {
            while (scan_input_0.hasNext()) {
                InternalRow scan_row_0 = (InternalRow) scan_input_0.next();
                ((org.apache.spark.sql.execution.metric.SQLMetric) references[0] /* numOutputRows */).add(1);
                boolean scan_isNull_0 = scan_row_0.isNullAt(0);
                UTF8String scan_value_0 = scan_isNull_0 ?
                        null : (scan_row_0.getUTF8String(0));

                generate_doConsume_0(scan_value_0, scan_isNull_0);
                if (shouldStop()) return;
            }
        }

        private void generate_doConsume_0(UTF8String generate_expr_0_0, boolean generate_exprIsNull_0_0) throws java.io.IOException {
            generate_generate_isNull_3_0 = true;
            UTF8String generate_value_3 = null;
            do {
                if (!generate_exprIsNull_0_0) {
                    generate_generate_isNull_3_0 = false;
                    generate_value_3 = generate_expr_0_0;
                    continue;
                }

                if (!false) {
                    generate_generate_isNull_3_0 = false;
                    generate_value_3 = ((UTF8String) references[1] /* literal */);
                    continue;
                }

            } while (false);

            ArrayData generate_value_2 = null;
            generate_value_2 = new org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.GenericArrayData(generate_value_3.split(((UTF8String) references[2] /* literal */), -1));

            int generate_numElements_0 = false ? 0 : generate_value_2.numElements();
            for (int generate_index_0 = 0; generate_index_0 < generate_numElements_0; generate_index_0++) {
                ((org.apache.spark.sql.execution.metric.SQLMetric) references[3] /* numOutputRows */).add(1);

// common sub-expressions

                UTF8String generate_col_0 = generate_value_2.getUTF8String(generate_index_0);

                generate_doConsume_1(generate_expr_0_0, generate_exprIsNull_0_0, generate_col_0);

            }

        }

    }
```

explain output

```
== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- Project [__fcol_4#345 AS table#482, __fcol_5#346 AS table-aaa#483, __fcol_7#335 AS table-bbb#484, __fcol_12#423 AS table-1#485]
   +- Project [__fcol_4#345, __fcol_5#346, __fcol_7#335, UDF(SPLITPART($0$, $1$, 1), , [$1$,$0$], [string_type,string_type], [], array(__fcol_11#417, __fcol_4#345), [], []) AS __fcol_12#423]
      +- Project [__fcol_1#330 AS __fcol_4#345, __fcol_3#323 AS __fcol_5#346, __fcol_7#335, UDF(",", , [], [], [], [], [], []) AS __fcol_11#417]
         +- Generate explode(split(coalesce(__fcol_1#330, ), :, -1)), [__fcol_1#330, __fcol_3#323], false, [__fcol_7#335]
            +- Project [__fcol_0#320 AS __fcol_1#330, __fcol_3#323]
               +- Generate explode(split(coalesce(__fcol_0#320, ), :, -1)), [__fcol_0#320], false, [__fcol_3#323]
                     +- Exchange SinglePartition, ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#210]
                           +- Project [table#252 AS __fcol_0#320]
                              +- Scan [table#252] PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<table:string>
```

I try to separate codegen to avoid this oom.
But i don't know how to do this, or there is a better way to solve this.

Comment: Can you add `.explain()` output for your query to the question?

Comment: I added, There are two explode function in this explain. There are about 10 explode function in oom condition.